# Display Filters in Datatables with just 2 decimals

Tags: r, format, rounding

I'm trying to do a filter based on this for DataTables: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html, the filter works fine but I need that the column searching filters for only what the table is displaying, for example:

ColumnB 2.312364 0.256899 8.858943

I'm using the FormatRound function so the table only shows 2 decimals so the column is being seen like this:

ColumnB 2.31 0.23 8.86

I need that the filter for the column searching, only filters for the data displaying in the table, currently if I filter i.e, the number 6, is showing the third and the first value which before the round also has a 6.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round the data before you put it into DataTables:

```
round(ColumnB, digits=2)
```